# E-commerce software with subdomain for multiple vendors but central administration

Tags: ecommerce

I'm looking for e-commerce software that allows personalized e-commerce sub-domains (templates are fine) for separate vendors (sub-domain.mainplatform.com). The users would buy the products on each sub-domain separately, but all the information would feed back into the main platform, where one person can see the orders and start producing the merchandise and deliver it. Each sub-domain should have a dashboard where the admins would be able to add and remove products, set the prices and payment methods.

Answer (score 1):

IT sounds like a job for Drupal since it is very flexible.
Look into Drupal 7 + Commerce at the moment, D8 is too young I guess.
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace

There are some caveats though and Ubercart is a bit longer in the game but it's less flexible than Commerce:
https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace

For the subdomains, there is a very nice solution:
https://www.drupal.org/project/domain
and an integration with Commerce:
https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_entity

Depending on your setup and requirements, you could still run into the need to do some custom coding - but that might happen when using Magento as well.